# Insert from temp table to a table with identity column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, identity-column

I'm grabbing some rows from a table, manipulating them in a temp table, and then looking to insert them as new rows into my original table.

However, I'm running into an issue with the identity column, even when I don't have the identity column on my temp table. The identity column is an auto-incrementing int.

This seems like a simple thing I'm way overthinking.

```
select top 0 *
into #TestTable
from OriginalTable;

...
--insert and manipulate records
...

ALTER TABLE #TestTable
DROP COLUMN MyIdentityColumn;

DECLARE @InsertedRows TABLE (NewSeqNum INT);

INSERT INTO OriginalTable
OUTPUT MyIdentityColumn INTO @InsertedRows(NewSeqNum)
SELECT * FROM #TestTable
```

but I get this error:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'OriginalTable' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

I absolutely do not want to set an explicit value, I want it to insert and give me the new identity (via `@InsertedRows`)

Comment: Don't use select * as your values. You need to explicitly state the columns. In your case this is failing because the parser does not evaluate every step logically. It still think that MyIdentityColumn is a column of #TestTable and thinks you are trying to insert it. Be explicit in your code. Specify the columns in the insert statement AND in the select statement you are using for the values.

Comment: @SeanLange is there a dynamic way to do that? Can I select the column names from the schema sans the ident column and use that instead of `*` or am I literally stuck listing them all out?

Comment: You should ALWAYS list the columns. If it is a large number of column you can drag the columns "folder" in SSMS to a query window. Anything other than the column being listed explicitly is lazy and prone to error down the road when the table changes.

Comment: @RandyHall Another tip apart the one from Sean Lange: if you are joining many tables you can add a short table alias (FROM MYTABLE AS M), and then as soon as you write the dot after alias name intellisense will show a list of available columns that you can insert using arrow to select + enter key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to keep the id of inserted records, then you need to specify all your columns but the id column in the select. As general good practice, dont select *, always specify the columns you want to retrieve-insert.

```
INSERT INTO OriginalTable (col1, col2, col3...)
OUTPUT MyIdentityColumn INTO @InsertedRows(NewSeqNum)
SELECT (col1, col2, col3...) FROM #TestTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you, I think your problem is that you're trying to insert '*' into the original table - which means *all* of your columns from the temp table.  Including your ID column (which you don't want to insert, because you're wanting it to auto-generate.)

Instead, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
Select [ColumnB],[ColumnC],[ColumnD],[Etc] into your temp table

Select [ColumnB],[ColumnC],[ColumnD],[Etc] into your original table.
```

... aka, spell out the columns explicitly, and omit the Identity column.